# Gradient framed environment

Tags: environments

How to make gradient framed environment like this image?[image]

Which package should I use? I'm a beginner in Latex, so I have no idea how to make it.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! What you try to do so far? Which `\documentclass` you use?  ...

Comment: I'm using book class with twoside option. I need this environment for toc, chapter page, section title, some exercise and project.

Comment: @Bolor: I assume the `gradient` should be in the frame colour fill?

Comment: @samcarter: That's similar to what I have tried, I think, see my deleted answer (which is possible because your are a >10k user meanwhile), but go ahead then, it's reopened ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Yes, I can see your answer, and it's similar in the sense that it is using `tcolorbox`. But I would like to try if maybe a shadow-only box is what the OP is looking for.

Comment: @samcarter: Seen and (+1) ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Thanks! I only hope it's what the OP is looking for.

Comment: @samcarter: He will show up and complain pretty soon, otherwise ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following approach is similar to the previous answer of [Christian Hupfer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/325681/36296), but instead if trying to make the gradients and frames fit your wishes, I think you don't really want a frame nor a gradient, try with the shadow alone:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox} 

\begin{document} 
    \begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced,colframe=white,colback=white, drop fuzzy shadow northwest] 
        Preface 
    \end{tcolorbox} 
\end{document}
```

[image]